# How to pass value from tableview cell Button action to other View controller by using Swift

Tags: swift

I want to pass value from TableView Cell button to another view controller . As I have button in TableView Cell I am facing problem while passing the value through button action.  please give answer in detail as i am Begineer.

Comment: Just set `yourButton.tag` in `cellForRow` then get selected button tag via `sender.tag` in your button action and access element from your table array and pass it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value from OneViewController to OtherViewController on TableViewCell's Button click using delegate approach.

```
class OneViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CustomCellDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "CustomCell"
        var cell : CustomCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! CustomCell?
        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomCell", owner: nil, options: nil)?[0] as? CustomCell
        }

        cell?.delegate = self
        return cell!
    }

    buttonClickAtIndex:(_ index : Int) {

       let value : Any = dataSource[index]
       let otherViewController : OtherViewController ///Create variable of OtherViewController
       otherViewController.value 
       /// push OtherViewController
    }

}

protocol CustomCellDelegate : class {

  func buttonClickAtIndex:(_ index : Int)
}

class CustomCell : UITableViewCell {

IBOutlet weak var button : UIButton!
weak var delegate : CustomCellDelegate?

   func buttonClick(_ sender : UIButton) {

      if let _delegate = delegate {
         _delegate.buttonClickAtIndex:(sender.tag)
      }
   }

}

class OtherViewController : UIViewController {

   var value : Any /// set Type and default value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using segues the method to pass from one view controller to the next is using a method called prepare(for:sender:). Whenever a segue gets triggered you provide code for data storing or any cleanup

Eg from apple developer website

Prepare the data object (seperate swift file for that perhaps) to be sent from source view controller (in this case MealViewController). A simple meal object is prepared to be sent.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

// Configure the destination view controller only when the save button is pressed.
guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, button === saveButton else {
    os_log("The save button was not pressed, cancelling", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    return
}

let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
let photo = photoImageView.image
let rating = ratingControl.rating

// Set the meal to be passed to MealTableViewController after the unwind segue.
meal = Meal(name: name, photo: photo, rating: rating) 
}
```

Next put these codes on the receiving end.

```
@IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? MealViewController, let meal = sourceViewController.meal {

        // Add a new meal.
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: meals.count, section: 0)

        meals.append(meal)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Here we first try to downcast it from UIViewController to MealViewController. And get the meal object and fill in the table for the meal. Don't worry if you don't understand everything going on here.

IMPORTANT parts are.

1 - In the Source View Controller.Create prepare method. Call super.prepare and create the object you want to send here.

2 - The receiving side create @IBAction func YOUMETHODNAME(sender: UIStoryboardSegue). Downcast the UIViewController to ur source view controller and get the object you created in the first step.

Hope this helps.

for more info refer
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html